# How to escpae dollar sign inside ssh command for Jenkins groovy?

Tags: ios, shell, jenkins, groovy, ssh

I have a groovy file that I used for my iOS job. `version=$(` gives syntax error when trying to build. If I escape the sign with `\$` that line doesn't work. How can I solve it?

```
stage('XCode')
{
     sh """
     if [ "${appName}" == "" ]; then
         echo "INVALID appName!"
         exit 1
     fi
     if [ "${schemeName}" == "" ]; then
         echo "INVALID Scheme Name!"
         exit 1
     fi

     /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion ${buildNumber}" "${WORKSPACE}/iOS_App/App/Supporting Files/AppProd-Info.plist"
     /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${WORKSPACE}/iOS_App/App/Supporting Files/AppProd-Info.plist"

     version=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "${WORKSPACE}/iOS_App/App/Supporting Files/AppProd-Info.plist")
     /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion ${buildNumber}" "${WORKSPACE}/iOS_App/App/AppNotifServiceExtensionProdInfo.plist" 
     /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $version" "${WORKSPACE}/iOS_App/App/AppNotifServiceExtensionProdInfo.plist" 

     /usr/bin/xcodebuild -quiet -workspace iOS_App/${workspaceName} -scheme ${schemeName} -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive -archivePath ${WORKSPACE}/build/${appName}.xcarchive
     /usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ${WORKSPACE}/build/${appName}.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist 'iOS_App/App/Supporting Files/${environment}_ExportOptions.plist' -exportPath ${WORKSPACE}/build
     """
}
```

I have escape the dollar sign I get below error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: version for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: Escape it and make it work ) What error do you have when it's escaped?

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: version for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: escape $ in $version also. because unescaped $version tries to find version var in groovy script, but it is getting defined in shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it by also escaping dolar sign on where I used it. Adding `\` to `:CFBundleShortVersionString \$version` solve the problem.